# Some GIFs can't be opened in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif

I have a lot of .gif images which can be viewed by e.g. IrfanView, but not opened in photoshop. Photoshop says it can't interpret the file format module (I'm using it in German, so I don't know the exact english error message).

When opening the file in a text editor, it starts with `gif89a`. I guess it has something to do with this type, but how can I open/edit gif89 files in photoshop?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that the main difference between working and not working ones is, that the broken ones contain `NETSCAPE2.0` in the first line in their source code where the others just have non-human-readable stuff. Both contain `gif89a`. Removing or editing the Netscape string breaks the file so it cannot be opened anymore in IrfanView.

Comment: All files or just a few? Can you re-save the gifs in InfranView and will they then open via Photoshop?

Comment: Irfanview opens almost anything in my experience. So I support re-saving them with it. If you have many, there is batch processing available in Irfanview as well.

Comment: The options to `save`/`save as...` are grayed out, as well as most options under `edit`.
Oh, this seems to be the case for every `gif` in IrfanView. And also the working files start with `gif89a`...

Comment: I found out something more (see update).

Comment: GIF89a is just the latest GIF standard. As you have noted, this is not the issue and I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: How many frames do the GIFs that won't open have?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the color mode is "Indexed color". Converting to another mode can make it edittable.[image]

Answer (score -1):

This format was removed from Photoshop around version 5.5. To restore it you will need to locate an older copy of Photoshop 5-8 and copy it from the "Goodies" folder into your Photoshop *plug-in/file formats* folder.

Here is an [older plug-in](https://rapidshare.com/files/4186433047/GIF89aExport.zip). I don't know your version of Photoshop. So I cannot guarantee it will work.

Comment: Photoshop should still support the GIF89a format. It simply doesn't save to that specific format. The gif89a format was rolled into Photoshop at version 5.5 because that was the first web-based version. It has not been removed ever. Removing it would mean Photoshop doesn't support transparency in gif files.

Comment: If it doesn't save as GIF89a, what flavour of GIF *does* it save as?